# ¿Cómo obtener la clave y el valor de un enum en angular?

Tags: typescript, angular-material

Requiero hacer un select con enumerados, en el cual se muestre un texto y el valor que almacene sea otro texto. Intenté de la siguiente manera pero obtengo el error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof UserRole'.   No index
> signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof UserRole'.ngtsc(7053)

TypeScript

```
export enum UserRole {
  STUDENT = 'Estudiante',
  CAREER_DIRECTOR = 'Director de carrera',
  AUTHORITY = 'Autoridad',
  FINANCIAL = 'Dirección Financiera'
}
keys = Object.keys;
userRoles = UserRole;
```

Html (utilizo Angular-Material)

```
<mat-select  required formControlName="role">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of keys(userRoles)" [value]="role">
        {{userRoles[role]}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede, es que no puede inferir el tipo del objeto del iterador, el cual por defecto es de tipo `string`.

Teniendo en cuenta el código que pusiste (un poco modificado para levantarse de forma aislada):

```js
export enum UserRole {
  STUDENT = 'Estudiante',
  CAREER_DIRECTOR = 'Director de carrera',
  AUTHORITY = 'Autoridad',
  FINANCIAL = 'Dirección Financiera'
}
const keys = Object.keys;
const userRoles = UserRole;
```

Al momento de ejecutar la función usando la directiva de Angular, lo que estarías ejecutando sería algo como esto:

```js
for (const role of keys(userRoles)) {
  console.log(userRoles[role]);
}
```

Sin embargo, ya que al momento de ejecutar la validación de tipos, role es de tipo `string`, no del tipo clave del enumerador `UserRole`. Esto se puede solucionar ejecutando un **assertion**:

```js
for (const role of keys(userRoles)) {
  const roleAsKey = role as keyof typeof userRoles;
  console.log(userRoles[roleAsKey]);
}
```

Pero claro, Angular no soporta esto en la template, por lo que tendrías que hacer uso de un método helper que permita deducir el tipo del valor, por ejemplo:

```js
export function getKeys<T>(enumerator: T) {
  return Object.keys(enumerator).map(key => key as keyof T);
}

for (const role of getKeys(UserRole)) { // También puedes poner userRoles como parámetro
  console.log(userRoles[role]);
}
```